# Base64 encoding in an Apigee Edge policy

Tags: apigee

What's the easiest way to do Base64 encoding within an Apigee policy? I need to encode the text of an SMS to be sent programmatically.

I know I could include the code explicitly, but I'd much prefer to use a capability that is built in if available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way to accomplish this is to create a [python script policy](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/customize-api-using-python), then use [python's built-in base64](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) module to build a simple function that base64-encodes or -decodes an argument.

If you snag the sample proxies from here: http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/api-proxy-samples you'll find a python example in `/simpleProxy/apiproxy/resources/py`.

The policy XML is like this:

```
<Script name="Script-GenerateAuthHeader">
  <ResourceURL>py://Authheader.py</ResourceURL>
</Script>
```

The python code would look like this:

```
import base64

username = flow.getVariable("request.formparam.client_id")
password = flow.getVariable("request.formparam.client_secret")

base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password))[:-1]

flow.setVariable("my.base64.blob", base64string)
```

Alternatively, if python isn't your style, [you could do this in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246813/1214800) using a js resource, or even directly in a [Node.js proxy](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/developing-nodejs-applications-apigee-edge).

Comment: Definitely easiest in python.

Comment: @Cheeso you have an example for that too? :)

Comment: Yes, I appended it here.

Answer (score 1):

The capability to simply inject a HTTP Basic Auth header, or to generate the base64 encoding of a string, is not built in, currently.

You can do it with a Javascript callout, like this.

policy XML:

```
<Javascript name='JavaScript-SetAuthz'>
  <ResourceURL>jsc://nameOfTheJavaScriptFileHere.js</ResourceURL>
</Javascript>
```

and [the JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/DinoChiesa/8431579)

Answer (score 1):

We also added a sample that shows how to do this in JavaScript:

https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/sample-proxies/base64encoder

Comment: This works. When working to incorporate it into an existing Api-Proxy manually, I had to upload the scripts `enc-utf16-min.js, enc-base64-min.js, core-min.js` by attaching each one to a javascript policy that I later deleted ... but not before adding the `<IncludeURL>` tags in my actual javascript policy that needed to reference them like so: https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/blob/master/sample-proxies/base64encoder/apiproxy/policies/EncodeAuthHeader.xml

Answer (score 1):

There is now newer functionality built into Apigee -- encodeBase64 and decodeBase64 built into Message templates. For more details see:
https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/message-template-intro#base64-encoding-functions

Answer (score 0):

-- Lack the reputation to comment (*such shame*) so adding an answer --

Since you asked specifically about encoding text and not binary content, you can make a minor improvement to Cheeso's answer by using [b64encode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) instead of encodestring:

```
base64string = base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))
```

This is also a tiny bit quicker in my testing.